# Will SQL update command complete if my C# application closes?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So this is an odd question but I am trying to determine the behavior of SQL Server. When I run an update command in SQL Server it is taking days to finish and I need to know what would happen if the user were to exit the program closing the connection.

Does the command get rolled back or does it complete?

Comment: The command will be rolled back as soon as SQL Server becomes aware the connection is dead.

Comment: I would suggest it will be terminated... not sure... but anyways: Maybe it would be a better approach to create e.g. a SSIS package for the update and trigger the execution of this package from SSIS? This should run even if the C# terminates...

Comment: Why is it taking days to finish anyway? Is it actually doing work for all that time or is it perhaps blocked?

Comment: If the process is taking days, then sounds like you have a more fundamental problem. Perhaps there's poor indexing or statistics? Are you updating a large volume of rows at the same time? If it's taking that long, are you at least doing it in batches, and committing them separately? There's far too little information for us to give you a definitive answer here. If you're not doing it in batches, how are you *not* filling the transaction log?

Comment: Don't wonder - test it yourself.

Comment: The relevant passage in the docs is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#errors-during-transaction-processing  `If the client application fails or if the client computer goes down or is restarted, this also breaks the connection, and the instance of the SQL Server Database Engine rolls back any outstanding connections when the network notifies it of the break.`

Comment: I'm not the one who writes the scripts I just made the application to run them. sorry for the confusion.